# Entity Framework one-to-many relation, updating the one side

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm, one-to-many

I have a set of endpoints which may or may not belong to an organization and an organization can have many or zeros endpoints in it. I want to remove a specific endpoint from an organization. I have written this method but I can't figure out why it is not working:

```
public void DeleteEndpointFromOrganization(Guid id, int organiationId)
{
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        var organization = GetOrganizationById(organiationId);
        var endpointSystem = organization.EndpointSystems.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        if (endpointSystem != null)
        {
            organization.EndpointSystems.Remove(endpointSystem);
        }

        db.Organizations.AddOrUpdate(organization);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you are modifying the `EndpointSystem` (many side), not the `Organization` (one side). Have you tried something like `endpointSystem.Organization = null` or `endpointSystem.OrganizationId = null` instead?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks mate!  didn't have a filed for foreign key, I added an optional field for foreign key and set that to null in my method and it workd.